# Can't send post request with cUrl when reading data from file

Tags: json, windows, curl

Hi I have a problem with sending using post command a jSon file.
I’m using curl in version 7.54.0 on windows.
I tried to execute command :

```
E:\Pobrane Na Big Data\cURL\curl-7.54.0-win64-mingw\bin>curl -v -X POST 
http://my.host.ip: 8083/api/kpi -H "content-type: application/json" -d 
@R.txt
```

And I get response:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying my.host.ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.host.ip (my.host.ip: 8083) port 8083 (#0)
> POST /api/kpi HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.host.ip: 8083
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 1398862
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 09:26:11 GMT
< Content-Length: 193
<
{"StatusCode":400,"StatusDescription":"System.NullReferenceException: Object ref
erence not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at KPI.WebApi.Controllers.KpiC
ontroller.<Post>d__2.MoveNext()"}* Connection #0 to host 10.23.2.124 left intact
```

What I would like to add,  is that when I’m tried to send the same file via postman there is no problem. File is successfully loaded via rest to DB. 
Also when I tried to put data directly into curl command, instead of using file, it successfully loaded data to DB. 
Any suggestion how to send this json file to rest with curl?

Comment: cURL doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your content-type to "application/json". Have you tried...

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"val"}' URL
```

So something like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}' http://my.host.ip: 8083/api/kpi
```

**UPDATE**

I see your file is a txt file "@R.txt" you need to provide a json file. and then

can you try this..

```
$ curl -vX POST  http://my.host.ip:8083/api/kpi -d @R.json \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

**If you want to still use the text file you can try this..**

```
 $ curl -F file=@R.txt http://my.host.ip:8083/api/kpi
```

**OR**

```
$ curl -X POST -d @R.txt http://my.host.ip:8083/api/kpi
```

and also make sure that you give absolute path to the file.

**Update 2.0**

```
curl http://my.host.ip:8083/api/kpi -H "Content-type:application/json" -X POST -d @R.txt
```

Comment: Sarbartha Rana unfortunately changing order of parameter in curl not solved the problem

Comment: Sarbarth Rana, thank you for replay. Unfortunately it not solved my problem. I would like to point out that file although it have extension txt, it contain json formatted data. (to be100% sure i also tested call with file with json extension). Another thing is that, as far as I remember, if you put curl with -f it mean that you want to post or get data from form in web. I need to post data to rest

Comment: yes you are correct -f is for getting the data from the web that was supposed to be -vX and also can you please try the update 2.0 code.

Comment: Sarbarth Rana, thank you for your update. Unfortunately it doesn’t work too. If afraid that simple change of order parameters in curl command won’t solve this.